# Mybatis interceptor modify sql parameter invalid

Tags: mybatis

[image]

When the `<foeeach>` tag exists in the sql of the xml file of mybatis, I use:

```
 @Intercepts({
@Signature(type = ParameterHandler. class, method = "setParameters", args = PreparedStatement. class),
})
```

Customize an interceptor to modify the parameters in sql, but the parameters used by mybatis when executing sql are still unmodified. After consulting the data, it seems that there are additional parameters (hasAdditionalParameter) in BoundSql. Is there a way to make AdditionalParameter be modified together?

Is there a way to make AdditionalParameter be modified together?